# ngrx effects combine action resposne with multiple selectors values

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

I have an Action defined **MyAction.loadDataSuccess**.
When ever **loadDataSuccess** is success ,we need to dispatch other three action.that am trying to implemented here. Other Actions needed **loadDataSuccess** response along with selectData1 and selectData2
Here is my code.

```
   loadSuccess$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(MyActions.loadDataSuccess),
    concatMap((action: any) => of(action).pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(selectData1)),
      withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(selectData2))
    )),
    switchMap(([payload, data1,data2]: any) => [
      FileActions.setSelectedName({ fileName: payload.name[0] }),
      PFDataActions.loadPFData({ data1: data1, data2:data2 }),
      OtherDataActions.loadOtherData(
        { data1: data1, data2:data2, otherName: ''}
      ),
      MainDataActions.loadMainData(
        { data1: data1, data2:data2, otherName: '' }
      ),
    ])
  ));
```

The above code was working when we have only one **withLatestFrom**.
Now the above code throwing **FileActions.setSelectedName** undefined.

How can we combine action response with two selector values
i have combined both  selectData1 and selectData2 into a single selector,but that won't worked.

Some one have any solutions, feel free to update

**Note:** `ngrx version-13`

Answer (score 0):

`withLatestFrom` can take multiple source observables: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/withLatestFrom

```
ofType(MyActions.loadDataSuccess),
withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(selectData1), this.store$.select(selectData2)),
switchMap(([payload, [data1,data2]]: any) =>
```

Comment: getting the same error

Comment: What is the specific error?

Comment: If it's the action undefined error that is unlikely required to WithLatestFrom

Comment: export const selectName = createSelector(
  dataStateFeatureSelector,
  (dataState: DataState): DataName => DataState.selectedName
  );. The error says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'selectName')"